# UINavigationBar height is reducing after re-enteringforeground

Tags: iphone, ios, screen-orientation

My controller main view call

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft animated:YES];
```

in it's `viewDidAppear`method because the screen **must** be manually rotated for the user.

Everything works perfectly except when I put the app in background and I re-enter foreground on this screen: Then the navigationBar's height become 32px.

If I comment the `setStatusBarOrientation` call, then no problem.

I've logged the navigationBar height in `didEnterForeground` method (after the super call), but it tells 44px. So I guess it would be resized *after*.

So I would like to know :

- If there was a way to prevent the navigationBar to be resized
- If no, what other callback method would come after the `didEnterForeground` one (`viewWill/DidAppear` does'nt)

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 4 months, I finally found a partial solution !

> - If no, what other callback method would come after the didEnterForeground one (viewWill/DidAppear does'nt)

I found a good callback when a **viewController** (not app delegate) is re-entering foreground. With `NSnotificationCenter`

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(willEnterForeground:) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
```

don't forget to remove

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
```

Comment: Seems like the only solution to me.
Did you stumble upon any other methods?

Comment: Nope, but have not searched since iOS7